# InnoDB error during mysql setup using docker

Tags: mysql, django, docker

I was trying to dockerize my existing django project, I read a lot of blogs about it, I was taking a reference of https://medium.com/@minghz42/docker-setup-for-django-on-mysql-1f063c9d16a0.

my docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'

services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.6.45
    ports:
      - '3306:3306'
    environment:
       MYSQL_DATABASE: 'new11_uat'
       MYSQL_USER: 'rootd'
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: '**********'
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: '**********'
  web:
    build: .
    command: python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - .:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.5-alpine

RUN apk add --update \
    build-base \
    gcc \
    libc-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libxslt-dev \
    mysql-dev \
    musl-dev \
    linux-headers \
    mariadb-dev \
    pcre-dev \
    mysql \
    mysql-client \
    python3 \
    python3-dev \
    py-pip \
  && rm -rf /var/cache/apk/*


RUN pip install mysqlclient
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY requirements_all.txt /code/

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements_all.txt

COPY . /code/
```

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': config('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': config('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': config('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': 'db',
        'PORT': 3306,
        'OPTIONS'  : { "init_command": "SET foreign_key_checks = 0;", },
    }
}
```

But when I try sudo docker-compose up, it give following error, I already tried to change the version of mysql but same problem

```
db_1   | Initializing database
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.45) starting as process 35 ...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist: a new database to be created!
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 12 MB
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:19 35 [Note] InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:20 35 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile101 size to 48 MB
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:21 35 [Note] InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 48 MB
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: Renaming log file ./ib_logfile101 to ./ib_logfile0
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45781
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:23 35 [Note] InnoDB: Creating tablespace and datafile system tables.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:24 35 [Note] InnoDB: Tablespace and datafile system tables created.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:24 35 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:24 35 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.45 started; log sequence number 0
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:32 35 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:32 35 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:32 35 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 35 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625977
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 0 [Note] Ignoring --secure-file-priv value as server is running with --bootstrap.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.6.45) starting as process 58 ...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.45 started; log sequence number 1625977
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:33 58 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:35 58 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625987
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | PLEASE REMEMBER TO SET A PASSWORD FOR THE MySQL root USER !
db_1   | To do so, start the server, then issue the following commands:
db_1   | 
db_1   |   /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root password 'new-password'
db_1   |   /usr/bin/mysqladmin -u root -h 4348c1636f61 password 'new-password'
db_1   | 
db_1   | Alternatively you can run:
db_1   | 
db_1   |   /usr/bin/mysql_secure_installation
db_1   | 
db_1   | which will also give you the option of removing the test
db_1   | databases and anonymous user created by default.  This is
db_1   | strongly recommended for production servers.
db_1   | 
db_1   | See the manual for more instructions.
db_1   | 
db_1   | Please report any problems at http://bugs.mysql.com/
db_1   | 
db_1   | The latest information about MySQL is available on the web at
db_1   | 
db_1   |   http://www.mysql.com
db_1   | 
db_1   | Support MySQL by buying support/licenses at http://shop.mysql.com
db_1   | 
db_1   | Note: new default config file not created.
db_1   | Please make sure your config file is current
db_1   | 
db_1   | WARNING: Default config file /etc/mysql/my.cnf exists on the system
db_1   | This file will be read by default by the MySQL server
db_1   | If you do not want to use this, either remove it, or use the
db_1   | --defaults-file argument to mysqld_safe when starting the server
db_1   | 
db_1   | Database initialized
db_1   | MySQL init process in progress...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.45) starting as process 86 ...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.45 started; log sequence number 1625987
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 8ba2c4b5-b930-11e9-9a72-0242ac130002.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Warning] 'user' entry '@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:36 86 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.6.45'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone1970.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:39 86 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | Warning: Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:39 86 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] mysqld: Normal shutdown
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Binlog end
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:40 86 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1625997
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_old_password'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 86 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
db_1   | 
db_1   | 
db_1   | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
db_1   | 
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.6.45) starting as process 1 ...
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: 128 rollback segment(s) are active.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:41 1 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] InnoDB: 5.6.45 started; log sequence number 1625997
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] IPv6 is available.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Warning] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/var/run/mysqld' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@4348c1636f61' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
db_1   | 2019-08-07 16:29:42 1 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
db_1   | Version: '5.6.45'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

Comment: Where is the error? your container is ready to accept connection

Comment: When I try to run my app container, it refuses to connect